# Replace swap implementation for built-in types in C++

Tags: c++

I want to change the behavior of `std::swap` for `char` type. According to what I have learned, the only a way to do this is to add a template specialization for `std::swap`, isn't it?

Since `char` is a built-in type, we have no chance to use ADL.

Please give your advice for such cases.

Edit: Here is the original problem I needed to solve. Random shuffle a string except that non-alpha characters should keep their positions unchanged.

The first thing I want to do is to leverage the `std::random_shuffle`.

Comment: Changing the behaviour of a built-in function when applied to a built-in data type? Why not create a new function, say `my::swap`, and use that?

Comment: I want to use it in std algorithms

Comment: What is your reasoning for only wanting to use the STL functions in this case? Creating your own function is more than enough to accomplish your task.

Comment: Adding your functions in `namespace std` is a bad practice. You can use other names.

Comment: Unless we are talking about something temporary for debugging or testing purposes, my advice is don't do it. Why would you want to change the behaviour of a standard function? Isn't that just going to confuse anyone and everyone who looks at your code. Write your own function, there is no reason that cannot work. Finally what do you want to change the behaviour to? It's hard to imagine what that could be.

Comment: what is the purpose of changing the behavior? Do you want only your application to use the new swap functionality (altered)? Or do you need both inherent and application functionality to be altered?

Comment: The story is, if I change the behavior of the swap, e.g. not swapping for specific chars, I can get a concise function by using std algorithms, or I have to invent the algorithm wheels

Comment: @haohaolee: Don't describe your problem, show it. Show what you're trying to do in code. The std algorithms are probably flexible enough for what you want.

Comment: With the real goal now added, it's clear that the original question doesn't actually help. `random_shuffle` won't create a random shuffle of a string when some of the swaps do not actually swap. This is easiest to see if you have a string with a million non-alpha's and just two alpha's. The chances of exactly that pair being swapped **directly** are 1E-12, not 50%. And they won't be swapped indirectly since that would involve a non-alpha that should stay fixed.

Comment: @MSalters I see your point. But the problem does not need strict uniform distribution, so it's not a big deal. However, by asking that question I learned that doing this is illegal.

Answer (score 2):

First: Don't do that. You may inadvertently break a different part of code that was previously working.

What you could try is to create your own class, make it hold only a single `char` element in it and then add any fancy functionality to it that you like. This way you would have your own `swap` behavior without breaking somebody elses code.

---

However, if you still want to do that, try the following (running) example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

namespace std {
template <>
void swap<char>(char& a, char& b) {
  std::cerr << "Swapped " << a << " with " << b << "\n";
  char t=a;
  a=b;
  b=t;
}
}

int main() {
  char arr[] = {'a', 'z', 'b', 'y'};
  std::reverse(arr, arr+4);
  return 0;
}
```

Do note that some stl algorithms may be specialized for basic types and not use `std::swap` at all.

---

**Ad. Edited question:**

Fair shuffling algorithm is fairly simple:

```
for (i = 0 .. n-2) {
  j = random (i .. n-1);  //and NOT random (0 .. n-1)
  swap(array[i], array[j]);
}
```

however, if you modify `swap` to prevent the operation when either of the arguments is not alphanumeric (I presume that's what you wanted to change swap into?), the remaining permutation is not going to be fair. With the increasing number of non-alhanumeric characters, the chance that given character won't move - increases. In worst-case scenario, imagine a long string with only two alphanumeric characters - the chance of them getting swapped will be near 0.

If you want to have fair permutation on only non-alpha characters you can do:

a) Pretty straightforward way - extract the alphanumeric characters to separate array, shuffle, and then put them back.

Simple, no performance hit, but needs more memory.

b) If the number of nonalphanumeric characters is relatively low, you can repeat the dice roll:

```
for (i = 0 .. n-2) {
  if (!alphanumeric(array[i]) continue;
  do {
    j = random (i .. n-1);
  while (!alphanumeric(array[j]));
  swap(array[i], array[j]);
}
```

This shuffling will be still fair, but will take a lot of time when you have a lot of nonalphanumeric characters.

Comment: It's UB to add anything to namespace std except specializations on UDTs fulfilling the requirements of what it's specializing.

Comment: @CygnusX1 This is actually what I come up with. That said, what is the dark side of this kind of code

Comment: @GManNickG may you please link me to the references which describe the UB

Comment: @haohaolee: §17.6.4.2.1 in the standard: "The behavior of a C++ program is undeﬁned if it adds declarations or deﬁnitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std unless otherwise speciﬁed. A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-deﬁned type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited."

Comment: @GManNickG Thanks. I see, it's indeed an UB